# Python, tkinter. Populate comboboxes using if statements

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently trying to code a programme with 3 comboboxes which are populated. For an example when the user picks "a" in the first combobox a new combobox should appear with new choices when "next" is pressed. Again the user puts in a value in the second combobox and presses "next", here a new combobox should appear with new choices. But somehow i cannot manage to show the third combobox.

Below the code is stated.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()

root.geometry("400x400")

cmb = ttk.Combobox(root, width="10", values=['a','b'])

def checkcmbo():


    if cmb.get() == "a":

         cmb2 = ttk.Combobox(root, width="10", values=['aa','ab'])

         cmb2.place(relx="0.1",rely="0.2")

         if cmb2.get() == "aa":

             cmb3 = ttk.Combobox(root, width="10", values=['car1','car2','car3'])

             cmb3.place(relx="0.1",rely="0.3")

         if cmb2.get() == "ab":

             cmb3 = ttk.Combobox(root, width="10", values=['ship1','ship2','ship3'])

             cmb3.place(relx="0.1",rely="0.3")



    if cmb.get() == "b":

         cmb2 = ttk.Combobox(root, width="10", values=['ba','bb'])

         cmb2.place(relx="0.1",rely="0.2")

         if cmb2.get() == "ba":

             cmb3 = ttk.Combobox(root, width="10", values=['racecar1','racecar2','racecar3'])

             cmb3.place(relx="0.1",rely="0.3")

         if cmb2.get() == "ab":

             cmb3 = ttk.Combobox(root, width="10", values=['reaceship1','raceship2','raceship3'])

             cmb3.place(relx="0.1",rely="0.3")



cmb.place(relx="0.1",rely="0.1")

btn = ttk.Button(root, text="Next",command=checkcmbo)

btn.place(relx="0.5",rely="0.1")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When you press "next" button each time,it will create a new `Combobox` widget and assign it to your `cmb2`.So every time `cmb2.get()` is `""`.

Comment: You want something like that: [dependant-combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60786641/python-dependant-combobox-based-on-sqlite-db-values/60841393)

Comment: You should bind `<<ComboboxSelected>>` event on `cmb` and `cmb2` to change the options of `cmb2` and `cmb3` respectively inside the event callback.

Comment: @acw1668. Thank you for aswering. I am not quite sure i understand what you mean, but i think you are right. Can you elaborate a little. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: When you bind `<<ComboboxSelected>>` event on a combobox, the event callback will be executed whenever an item of the combobox is selected.  So you can populate another combobox in the event callback based on the selected item.